# Server error asp.net after deleting Editor from admin panel who posts some stuff on website

Tags: asp.net, webforms

i'm using this code to show "added by" label on admin panel but after deleting that specific user i got error

code :

```
         <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# getAdminName(Convert.ToInt32(Eval("user_id"))) %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>   


        </asp:TemplateField>
```

but if i remove this pages of panel works fine but "added by" label not showing up. any help to get rid of this ? i want to show "added by" label even after deleting editor or author without getting error

Comment: This is web forms code - it has nothing to do with asp.net-mvc

Comment: What kind of error you've got? What `getAdminName` returns? I guess `Convert.ToInt32` throwing exception if the `Eval` result not returning integer number.

Comment: What is happening inside `getAdminName`?

Comment: sequence contains no elements

Comment: Then check existence of `First()`, `Last()` or `Single()` which returns no results. Try using `FirstOrDefault()`, `LastOrDefault()` or `SingleOrDefault()` instead.